# using django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-allauth

i am having trouble using django-allauth. I am getting this error.

NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
Reverse for 'facebook_channel' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

So far I have followed everything to the letter.

here is my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'app',
    'uni_form',
    'emailconfirmation',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
)


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "allauth.context_processors.allauth",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

also i have added facebook secret and app id from admin module the allauth provides.

looking forward to a quick reply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just faced and solved the same problem. You need to install the Facebook SDK egg, which django-allauth relies on, i.e.:

```
pip install -e git://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk.git#egg=facebook-sdk
```

(By the way, if you are using Django 1.4, you will run into a runtime error when confirming email addresses due to django-allauth not using the new timezone-aware dates. The quick-fix is to set

```
USE_TZ = False
```

in your settings.py.)

Comment: haha thanks. i did runinto the TZ error just now, and your post came in very very handy. <3