# django-allauth facebook integration not working

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am getting the following error.

Reverse for 'facebook_channel' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

The following line is red.

```
{% providers_media_js %}
```

These are my settings from local_settings.py

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
{'facebook':
    {'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
     'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
     'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
     'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_GB',
     'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False}}

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
```

settings.py

```
SITE_ID = 1

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
# `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.request',
# allauth specific context processors
'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
'suit',
'debug_toolbar',
'south',
'crispy_forms',
'haystack',
'taggit',
'bootstrapform',
'sorl.thumbnail',
)
```

Yes, I have done the model migrations, I have the four tables that allauth creates.

Any help will be much appreciated, it's been bugging me for a while.

**Updated**

Main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   url(r'^accounts/', include('useraccount.urls')),
                   url(r'^directory/', include('directory.urls')),
                   ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += url(r'', 'directory.views.home', name='home'),

if settings.DEBUG:
import debug_toolbar

urlpatterns += patterns('',
                        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
                        )
```

**Updated**

urls.py inside useraccount app

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required
from useraccount.views import AccountView, ProfileUpdateView, ProfileDetailView


urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   (r'^logout', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': 'directory_home'}),
                   url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\w+)', ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='useraccount_profile'),
                   url(r'^edit', login_required(ProfileUpdateView.as_view()), name='useraccount_edit'),
                   url(r'^dashboard', login_required(AccountView.as_view()), name='useraccount_dashboard'),
                   url(r'', include('allauth.account.urls')),
                   )
```

Comment: Are you calling ```{% load socialaccount %}``` in that template?

Comment: No, I just copied the default login.html template. I will try loading that.

Comment: I'm guessing that worked?

Comment: Sorry didn't get chance to do it...C# day job. Will do when I get home but I am very hopeful. Thanks will update you.

Comment: I am afraid, still the same error. I added {% load socialaccount %} to login.html that I copied from the default templates that come with django-allauth

Comment: And looking at the template its trying to load which is /python3.3/site-packages/allauth/templates/socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html it already has {% load socialaccount %} on the first line.

Comment: does this solve it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065610/using-django-allauth

Comment: does /accounts/facebook/channel/ show up in your urls?

Comment: No, nothing matches that route.

Comment: The actual error's occurring in allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.provider at line 105 - FacebookProvider.media_js(). What does your urls.py look like, have you included all the allauth urls? Do the /accounts/social/ urls show up?

Comment: if you replace url(r'^accounts/', include('useraccount.urls')) with url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')) does that fix it?

Comment: @james thanks a lot, I just realised I had url(r'', include('allauth.account.urls')) instead of url(r'', include('allauth.urls')),

Comment: @james if you write that as an answer I can mark it as solved.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar no problem, glad to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to include the correct allauth urls in your url conf

```
url(r'', include('allauth.urls'))
```