# facebook integration error, django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I want to integrante django allauth to my website, I followed the tutorial but I am facing an error while I use ElasticBeanStalk servers but not on localhost.

```
Reverse for 'facebook_login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Here is my **settings** :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'utilisateur',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
    }
}
```

**urls.py** :

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

[image]

This error only raise on the page : 'MyDomain/accounts/login/' when logged out, also there is no links for 'facebook/login/' as on localhost.

I already configured the facebook application, with the ElasticBeanStalk URL.

Any help would be appreciated, I am on it for a while now, how can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on another post : Facebook SDK egg which allauth relies on was missing on the webserver ElasticBeanStalk.

You can learn more on this post : [using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065610/using-django-allauth?rq=1)